# Is it possible to insert a row only to a partition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-partitioning

I have an already exist table which I want to be divided.
Here is my script for partitions creating:

```
create or replace function create_partition_and_insert_to_partition_bundle() returns trigger as
$$
declare
    partition text;
    dt_constraint text;
begin
    dt_constraint := format( 'y%sq%s', (select date_part('year', date(new.created))), select ceil(date_part('month', date(new.created))::float / 3));
    partition := format( 'bundle_%s', dt_constraint);
    if not exists(select relname from pg_class where relname = partition) then
        execute 'create table '||partition||' (like bundle including all) inherits (bundle)';
    end if;
    execute 'insert into ' || partition || ' values ( ($1).* )' using new;
    return null;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger create_insert_partition_bundle before insert on bundle for each row execute procedure create_partition_and_insert_to_partition_bundle();

set constraint_exclusion = partition;
```

When I add a new row, the trigger runs and creates a new partition for a new quart, but the row is also inserted to a parent table `bundle`. Is it possible to insert only to a partition, and how should I change my script?

Comment: This works correctly for me (once I remove the extra 'select' before 'ceil' which causes a syntax error).  The row is inserted only into the child.  It *shows up* in the parent when queried (without ONLY), because that is how partitioning works.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i found inheritance very hard to understand. So I use partition.
The following is using partition.You don't even need trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE  bundle (
bundle_id   int not null,
created date not null,
misc    text
) PARTITION BY RANGE (created);

CREATE TABLE bundle_y2022q1 PARTITION OF bundle
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-01-01') TO ('2022-04-01');
CREATE TABLE bundle_y2022q2 PARTITION OF bundle
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-04-01') TO ('2022-07-01');
CREATE TABLE bundle_y2022q3 PARTITION OF bundle
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-07-01') TO ('2022-10-01');    
CREATE TABLE bundle_y2022q4 PARTITION OF bundle
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-10-01') TO ('2023-01-01');
```

Comment: The table already exists and has more than 1 million rows, so now partitioning without inheritance is impossible

Comment: Oh, yes, it is possible: attach your current table as partition.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorry, I didn't got your advice

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe could you describe it with a piece of code, please

Comment: But this isn't going to create new partitions automatically, as he is attempting to do.

Comment: My idea in short: `ALTER TABLE tab RENAME TO tab_old; CREATE TABLE tab (LIKE tab_old) PARTITION BY RANGE (ts); ALTER TABLE tab ATTACH PARTITION tab_old FOR VALUES FROM (MINVALUE) TO ('2022-09-06');` True, new partitions won't be created automatically.